Angular 18 SSR fetches data from the server but does not populate HTML with the data
I am new to Angular, and I was working with Angular 18, for a project, I wanted to fetch some data from my CMS and then populate my HTML template with the CMS data. I created a service for this and fetched the data from my CMS and got back the response.
However, when I tried to assign this data to my angular component variable, it seems to be empty, although the response data from the CMS is correct. Here is the code that I was working on.
The service that fetches data from the CMS.
// cmsHttpResponse is defined 

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root',})
export class CmsService {httpOptions = {headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json',}),observe: 'response',};constructor(private http: HttpClient,) {}

get<cmsHttpResponse>(endpoint: CMSEndPoint,params?: string,showLoader = false): Observable<cmsHttpResponse> {const url = endpoint.getUrl(params);

return this.http
  .get<cmsHttpResponse>(endpoint.getUrl(params), {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Authorization token`,
      }),
      observe: 'response',
  })
  .pipe(
    map((response) => {
      const cmsResponse = new cmsHttpResponse();
      cmsResponse.responseData = response.body;
      cmsResponse.responseCode = response.status;

      switch (response.status) {
        case 200:
          cmsResponse.success = true;
          return cmsResponse;
        default:
          return throwError(
            () => new Error(`Unexpected status code ${response.status}`)
          );
      }
    }),
    catchError(this.handleError<any>(endpoint.getUrl(params)))
  );

}
private handleError<T>(url = '') {// function to handle error}

}

and here is my component.ts in which I inject my cms-service

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header-desktop',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [FormsModule, NgIconComponent, MatExpansionModule],
  templateUrl: './header-desktop.component.html',
  styleUrl: './header-desktop.component.scss',
  viewProviders: [provideIcons({ ionTriangle, ionClose, ionChevronDown })],
})
export class HeaderDesktopComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  // booleans
  showInput = false;
  showSuggestions = false;
  panelOpenState = false;
    
  // data variables
  menus:Menu[] = []

  // state variables for UI
  hoverIndex = -1;
  submenuClickIndex = -1
  childmenuClickIndex = -1
  menuClick = -1;

  // services
  private service = inject(CmsService);
  private siteApiservice = inject(SiteApiService);

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private renderer: Renderer2,
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object
  ) {
    afterNextRender(() => {
      // unrelated to error, for scroll detection
      this.onWindowScroll();
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getMenu(); <--------------- called this when component rendered
  }
  
  ngOnDestroy(){
    // unrelated to the error, for unsubscribing from a subscription
    this.suggestedDataSubscription?.unsubscribe();
  }

  getMenu():void{
    this.service
      .get<cmsHttpResponse>(
        CMSEndPoint.API_CMS_GET_NAVIGATION,
        'query-string'
      )
      .subscribe({
        next:(response:cmsHttpResponse)=>{
          if(response.success){
            const data = response.responseData as MainMenu;
            // -------------- here printing data works, correct data is here --------
            this.menus = data.data?.filter(
                    (s) =>
                      s.attributes?.position == 'Header' &&
                      s.attributes.menu_name != 'Resources'
                  ) ?? [];
            // --------------- here printing anything does not work, this.menus is not printing, data is not printing ------------------
          }
        },error:(error)=>{
          //error block
        }
      });
    }
}

and here is the HTML template that I want to render
<nav
  id="desktop-header"
  class="hidden md:flex md:flex-row nav-header-active fixed top-0 left-0 right-0 z-20 rounded-full m-4 p-3 items-center justify-between"
>
  <div class="flex flex-row items-center relative">
    <!-- show menus -->
    @if(!showInput) {

    <!-- (mouseleave)="hoverIndex=-1" to hide the submenu drop-down -->
    <div
      (mouseleave)="hoverIndex = -1"
      class="flex flex-row relative justify-center items-center gap-2 z-20 text-sm text-white overflow-visible"
    >
      // ----------------CMS DATA THAT NEEDS TO BE PUT HERE---------
      <!-- iterate over each menu item -->
      @for (menu of menus; track $index) {

      <button
        (mouseenter)="hoverIndex = $index"
        class="menu-item font-barlow"  
      >
        <div class="flex items-center">
          <p class="pr-1" (click)="hoverIndex === $index ? (hoverIndex = -1) : (hoverIndex = $index)">{{ menu.attributes.menu_name }}</p>
          <ng-icon size="6" name="ionTriangle" class="dropdown-icon"></ng-icon>
        </div>
        
        @if(hoverIndex===$index){
        <!-- for single menu with no child menu -->
        @if(typeofMenu(menu, "desktop")===menu_types.SINGLE_COLUMN_WITHOUT_CHILD){
        <div
          class="dropdown-content grid grid-cols-1 gap-2 p-2 text-left text-nowrap rounded"
        >
          <!-- iterate over each submenu -->

          // ----------------CMS DATA THAT NEEDS TO BE PUT HERE---------
          @for (submenu of menu.attributes.menus.data; track $index) {
          <a
            href="{{ submenu.attributes.url }}"
            class="flex flex-row items-center justify-start w-full p-2 gap-2"
          >
           // ----------------CMS DATA THAT NEEDS TO BE PUT HERE---------
            {{ submenu.attributes.submenu }}
          </a>
          }
        </div>
        <!-- for double menu with no child menu -->
        } @else if(typeofMenu(menu, "desktop")===menu_types.DOUBLE_COLUMN_WITHOUT_CHILD){
        <div
          class="dropdown-content grid grid-cols-2 gap-2 p-4 w-fit text-left rounded"
        >
          <!-- divide the grid into 2 columns, half submenus in each -->
          <div class="col-auto">
            @for (submenu of menu.attributes.menus.data | slice : 0 :
            firstColumnMenuCount(menu.attributes.menus.data); track $index) {

            <a
              href="{{ submenu.attributes.url }}"
              class="p-2 flex flex-row items-center gap-2"
              >// svg image
// ----------------CMS DATA THAT NEEDS TO BE PUT HERE---------
              {{ submenu.attributes.submenu }}
            </a
            >

            }
          </div>
          <div class="col-auto">
            @for (submenu of menu.attributes.menus.data | slice :
            firstColumnMenuCount(menu.attributes.menus.data) :
            menu.attributes.menus.data.length; track $index) {
            <a
              href="{{ submenu.attributes.url }}"
              class="p-2 flex flex-row items-center gap-2"
              >
// ----------------CMS DATA THAT NEEDS TO BE PUT HERE---------
              {{ submenu.attributes.submenu }}</a
            >
            }
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- for double menu with child menu -->
        } @else { 
          <!-- DOUBLE COLUMN MENU WITH CHILD -->
        <div
          class="dropdown-content grid grid-cols-2 gap-2 p-1 w-fit text-left rounded"
        >
          <!-- divide the grid into 2 columns, half submenus in each -->
          <div class="col-auto">
            @for (submenu of menu.attributes.menus.data | slice : 0 :
            firstColumnMenuCount(menu.attributes.menus.data); track $index) {
            <mat-accordion>
              <mat-expansion-panel
                hideToggle
                class="bg-transparent mat-elevation-z0 hover:bg-transparent"
              >
                <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                  <mat-panel-title class="text-nowrap">
// ----------------CMS DATA THAT NEEDS TO BE PUT HERE---------
                    {{ submenu.attributes.submenu }}
                  </mat-panel-title>
                  <mat-panel-description>
                    @if(panelOpenState===true){ - }@else { + }
                  </mat-panel-description>
                </mat-expansion-panel-header>
                <ul class="font-barlow list-item">
                  @for(child_menu of submenu.attributes.child_menu; track
                  $index){
                  <li class="py-1 list-inside">
                    <a href="{{ child_menu.menu_url }}">
// ----------------CMS DATA THAT NEEDS TO BE PUT HERE---------
                      {{ child_menu.menu_name }}
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  }
                </ul>
              </mat-expansion-panel>
            </mat-accordion>
            }
          </div>
          <div class="col-auto">
            @for (submenu of menu.attributes.menus.data | slice :
            firstColumnMenuCount(menu.attributes.menus.data) :
            menu.attributes.menus.data.length; track $index) {
            <mat-accordion class="drop-shadow-none">
              <mat-expansion-panel
                hideToggle
                class="bg-transparent mat-elevation-z0 hover:bg-transparent"
              >
                <mat-expansion-panel-header class="drop-shadow-none">
                  <mat-panel-title class="text-nowrap">
// ----------------CMS DATA THAT NEEDS TO BE PUT HERE---------
                    {{ submenu.attributes.submenu }}
                  </mat-panel-title>
                  <mat-panel-description>
                    @if(panelOpenState===true){ - }@else { + }
                  </mat-panel-description>
                </mat-expansion-panel-header>
                <ul class="flex flex-col marker:list-disc font-barlow">
                  @for(child_menu of submenu.attributes.child_menu; track
                  $index){
                  <li class="py-1">
                    <a href="{{ child_menu.menu_url }}">
// ----------------CMS DATA THAT NEEDS TO BE PUT HERE---------
                      {{ child_menu.menu_name }}
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  }
                </ul>
              </mat-expansion-panel>
            </mat-accordion>
            }
          </div>
        </div>
        } }
      </button>
      }
    </div>
    }
  </div>

  </div>
</nav>

I don't think this has anything to do with async call because the data from the fetch request is coming properly, I don't understand why my menus object is not assigned the values and why the HTML is not populated on the server side, the values that should be there are not available on the page source of my project and the instead a call to the server from the client is also made to populate the HTML client side.
I've looked into the Angular 18 docs and there wasn't much that helped me, I looked into several articles on how angular SSR work and how does client hydration works but nothing seems to work and I also looked into this one youtube video by Monsterless Academy and followed his way but still had the same issue.
Here is the video that I watched -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4KH-TStaiGw&t=13s

Do u see any errors in the console?
